# Get the list of artifacts from teamcity build and download only exact one

Tags: perl, rest, teamcity

I am struggling to download only one artifact from `lastsuccessful` teamcity build.

Ofc, I can download all artifacts and then find one on my storage using
http://teamcity/repository/downloadAll/buildTypeId/.lastSuccessful/
but it is a huge waste of time and traffic.

How can I get the list of artifacts in the `lastSuccessful` build?
If I could get the list, then I would be able to form download request and get only the artifact I need.

i.e. my build has:

- SetupSoft..buildId.zip
- Libs..buildId.zip
- Binaries..buildId.zip

Suppose I need only Binaries.zip from that build, so if I am to find the list of artifacts, I would choose Binaries using regex(or whatever) and then create download link like so:

http://teamcity/repository/download/#buildTypeId#/#buildId#/binaries<..>.zip

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I've found solution.
Here is the list of possible locators:

```
Supported dimensions are: [id, taskId, project, affectedProject, buildType, branch, 
agent, user, personal,  state, tag, property, compatibleAgent, number, status, canceled, 
pinned, queuedDate, startDate, finishDate, sinceBuild, sinceDate, untilBuild,   untilDate, 
failedToStart, snapshotDependency, 
artifactDependency, hanging, history, defaultFilter, $singleValue, start, lookupLimit]
```

specifying url using couple of them can provide one the arifacts list i.e. :
http://teamcity/app/rest/builds/buildType:xxxx,state:finished/artifacts/

Answer (score 4):

TeamCity have api. Use it.
List of artifacts:

```
http://teamcity:8008/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:75105/artifacts
```

In my case i have several folders in artifact directory, choosing one, getting list of files inside:

```
http://teamcity:8008/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:75105/artifacts/children/Scripts
```

It looks like:

```
<files count="1">
<file name="000-201704070732-000000-00000-0160609.07.Build-0088.01.Schema.sql" size="88340" modificationTime="20170407T074931+0300" href="/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:75105/artifacts/metadata/Scripts/000-201704070732-000000-00000-0160609.07.Build-0088.01.Schema.sql">
<content href="/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:75105/artifacts/content/Scripts/000-201704070732-000000-00000-0160609.07.Build-0088.01.Schema.sql"/>
</file>
</files>
```

Then just make GET of:

```
http://teamcity:8008/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:75105/artifacts/content/Scripts/000-201704070732-000000-00000-0160609.07.Build-0088.01.Schema.sql
```

And you will took file you need only, Thats all. :)

Comment: that's all great, but I do not know the build ID you mentioned in the link (id:75105), all I have is build type Id(which is string value) and that I need only last successfull build. How do I manage to get artifacts in this case? 
I've tried using 'buildTypeId=mybtt', but it is prohibited: Invalid single value: 'buildTypeId=mybtt'. Should be a number.

Comment: @Amarula
You can do like this:  
`$APIURL = "${API_BaseUrl}/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/?locator=buildType:${API_BuildType},state:finished,count:1"`  
Easy way to get top 1 successful build. Then, you obtain the "ID"